# Always showing No route matches path "/" when using react-rotuer

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am very new to react. I tried to use react-router. But no matter how I change the code, it always give me the warning.

> Warning: No route matches path "/". Make sure you have  somewhere in your routes

After googling for few hours, still have no idea what is wrong. Can anyone give me some hint? Thank you

In my app.js

```
Router.run(routes, Router.HistoryLocation, function(Handler, routerState) {
var params = routerState.params;
React.render(
    <Handler params={params}/>,
    document.getElementById('react-app')
    )
});
```

In my route.js

```
var routes = (
<Route name="root" path="/" handler={App}>
    <DefaultRoute handler={Home} />
    <Route name="commitments" handler={CommitmentList} />
    <Route name="commitment" handler={Commitment} />
</Route>
);
```

I am also use express and tring to do server-side rendering,

```
module.exports = {

  index: function(req, res) {
        var path = req.url;
        Router.run(routes, req.url, function(Handler) {
            var handler = React.createElement(Handler);
            var markup = React.renderToStaticMarkup(handler);
            res.render('home', {
                markup: markup // Pass rendered react markup
            });
         });

  }
}
```

Comment: This happened to me as well. I am using meteor. I switched from Flow Router to React Router. I successfully implemented React Router, and everything was working great but in my console, I kept getting this error "There is no route for path : / ". What I had to do is remove Flow Router, and everything was fine again. I forgot to remove it after implementing React Router.

Answer (score 0):

Your App handler is missing in app.js